# datepicker only visible once in asp.net using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on adding a date picker to date fields in my aspx page. What I want to accomplish here is to attach datepicker to the id of the input. These fields are created dynamically. I am having issues with the date picker as it is visible the first time I click on the input but wont show up again until page refresh. I would appreciate any help. Here is what I have tried.

My input field:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$SubsModifier$tbDate" type="text" value="06/21/2016"  onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$SubsModifier$tbDate\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ctl00_MainContent_SubsModifier_tbDate" class="form-control">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("[id*=tbDate]").datepicker({
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
    });
});
```

I have noticed that "hasDatePicker" is visible in the class the first time and is removed when I select a date from the datepicker.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: No errors. It works the first time so there are no errors.

Comment: Open the console and refresh the page, see if there are any javascript errors. It can run on the first time, but when you run again it may find some errors that stops javascript from working

Comment: Tried that too and no errors on the page.

Comment: I would say it's the [id*=tbDate] selector, but it works on the first run. Try changing to to [id$=tbDate]

Comment: Do you do any postbacks?

Comment: Also, what datepicker are you using? jQuery UI?

Comment: Nope. No postbacks and jquery datepicker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115143/discussion-between-felipe-deguchi-and-nepcoder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Felipe Deguchi and @arturas for their help. I modified arturas answer into the following and it is working as expected. Here is what I did.

```
$('body').on('focus', ".date-picker", function () {
    $(".date-picker").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have `class = "form-control"`  as input attribute. Add additional pseudo class `class = "form-control date-picker"` and try then:

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap the method in a function

```
function RunMeAfterControlsAreGenerated() {
    $("[id$=tbDate]").datepicker({
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
    });
}
```

Then call it after you dynamically generate your controls on Code Behind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "RunMe", "RunMeAfterControlsAreGenerated();",true);
```